# How to use JavaScript to replace an attribute inside a span tag?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to update the data-value attribute's value in the code below with a dynamic integer value I will return in a small JS code I wrote. My code will generate a different integer based on a few factors that vary day to day, but in any case, it returns one single integer value that I want to insert into the data-value attribute.

I have a current solution that works but is "ugly" I think. I basically used DOM manipulation to hide the value the code below produces in the UI, and implemented my own counter from 0 to the dynamic integer value. Is there a more direct and "proper" way of solving the problem, something like innerHTML but maybe for attributes? Thanks!

```html
<div class="content-box-percentage content-box-counter" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:60px;line-height:normal;">
<i class="counter-box-icon fontawesome-icon fa-mug-hot fas" style="font-size:70px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<span class="display-counter" data-value="21" data-direction="up" data-decimals="0">0</span>
</div>
```

Thanks

EDIT: adding the "ugly" code I had, as requested. Originally I had the class ID bsa-counter in the first code snippet. As I was looking to make it prettier (therefore the reason for my post in the first place), I removed the class ID and the JS code as I was planning on starting over.

```js
    "use strict";

    // CounterBox multiplier - multiplies the number of days by an integer
    const bsaMultiplier = 3;

    // Customize counter boxes to support counting from a start date to the current date, in number of days

    // Run custom counter box function, passing in bsaMultiplier
    bsaCounterBoxToToday(bsaMultiplier);

    function bsaCounterBoxToToday(bsaMultiplier) {
      const bsaStartDateC = "2019/07/14"; // enter in the format of "YYYY/MM/DD", including quotes
      const bsaDomElementId = "bsa-counter"; // DOM ID element to select
      const bsaDomElementClass = "display-counter"; // DOM Class element to select
      const bsaCounterDuration = 500;

      // Date range
      const bsaStartDate = new Date(bsaStartDateC);
      const bsaToday = new Date(
        `${new Date().getFullYear()}/${
          new Date().getMonth() + 1
        }/${new Date().getDate()}`
      );

      // Days * multiplier
      const bsaCountToValue =
        Math.ceil(Math.abs(bsaToday - bsaStartDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) *
        bsaMultiplier;

      let bsaCurrentValue = 0;

      let bsaIncrSpeed = setInterval(() => {
        bsaCurrentValue < bsaCountToValue
          ? (document
              .getElementById(bsaDomElementId)
              .getElementsByClassName(bsaDomElementClass)[0].textContent =
              ++bsaCurrentValue)
          : clearInterval(bsaIncrSpeed);
      }, bsaCounterDuration / 100);
    }
```

Comment: _"I have a current solution that works but is "ugly" I think"_ Post it please

Comment: As @j08691 has written, please post your code so that we know *exactly* what you want done.

Comment: Added my ugly code. In case it's not clear, I'm not trying to come up with my own counter - that's just my workaround. What I really want done is to replace the data-value attribute, because the actual counting behavior is already done somewhere else. My ugly code is simply reinventing the wheel because I didn't know how to overwrite the data-value attribute dynamically on page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be what you're looking for:

```
var yourInt = 4;
document.getElementsByClassName("display-counter")[0].setAttribute("data-value", parseInt(yourInt));
```

There are multiple ways of getting the span element's DOM, but this is one way if your span element is first on your html doc. Consider using an id and the "getElementById()" function instead:

```
document.getElementById("the-id-name-you-added").setAttribute("data-value", parseInt(yourInt));
```

change your span to be:

```
<span id="the-id-name-you-added" class="display-counter" data-value="21" data-direction="up" data-decimals="0">0</span>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a go.